# Manage item displayed in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using a custom arrayadapter.

And I would like to say: "ok, in this position don't create the item".

Here is the code:

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

            View itemView = convertView;
            // Make sure we have a view to work with
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_critere, parent, false);
            }


            // Find the car to work with
            Criteria currentCriteria = mCriteria.get(position);


            // Fill the view
            ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.critere_title)).setText(currentCriteria.getName());
            String text;
            if (currentCriteria.isNumber()) {
                text = currentCriteria.getIntValue() + " " + currentCriteria.getUnity();
            } else {
                // get Selected values in a String[]
                String[] resultTab = currentCriteria.getTabTextValue();
                text = new String();

                //Convert String[] in String
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < resultTab.length; i++) {
                    if (i != 0)
                        text += ", ";
                    text += resultTab[i];
                }
            }
            ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.critere_value)).setText(text);

            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

I was thinking about manage the method which calls getView() but I dunno which one is it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't control getView() calls. Your issu is not very clear, getview must return a cell (View). That's up to you to do what is necessary to create only cell you need :/

Comment: Why not filter your data from the beginning based on the criteria

Comment: Because the listA display what the listB doesn't. So when I want remove an item from b and display it in A. I just need to set the object.isdisplayed = false and call notifyDataSetChanged() for both of lists

Comment: check this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/a/7613620/1396082